# ioctl consumes longer when there is heavy sd card operation

Tags: android, linux, kernel, streaming

I'm working on an android based embedded system. I'm checking the camera recording performance on the system.

For performance tuning purpose I wrote 2 native apps. The camera app is dequeing the buffer from v4l2 and then send it to encoder to do encoding. And then the encoded data is discarded.

The test_emmc app opens a file on sd card and writes the dummy data to file. The test_emmc app supports 2 writing modes: streaming mode: which simulates the streaming app, writing the frame in every 33ms; fast mode: which writes the data as fast as possible.

If I run my camera app standalone, it is running smoothly. The ioctl to venc and v4l2 returns quickly. But if I run both app simultaneous, especially if I run the test_emmc app at fast mode, the camera app starts droping frame. It can't dequeue the buffer timely. And I found that the calling to venc sometimes becomes very very longer.

My system has 4 cores. I checked the system status, even the test_emmc is running at fast mode, the cpu utilization is only ~15%, so there should be enough CPU resource. The Linux kernel may block the test_emmc process if it is flushing the page to SD Card. But the camera app should be unimpacted, right? So who blocks the ioctl to venc and v4l2 in camera app?